# Usage of vDSP_nzcros for zero crossing in audio programming

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing

I want to do zero crossing on iOS audio input sample data. As reference from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html), a vdsp_nzcros funcion could count the zero crossing. However, I do have an error that no matching function for vdsp_nzcros when I try to put some dummy variable inside

Here is the code

> //r1 is a float *
>
> //r2 and r3 is int *
>
> //other number just randomly put it.
>
> vDSP_nzcros(r1, 1, 5000, r2, r3, 312);

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: You need to add the Accelerate framework to your project and #include/#import vDSP.h

Comment: I cannot find the vDSP.h location. However I do **#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>**

Comment: Have you also added the Accelerate framework to your project ? Note that vDSP.h is in the vecLib framework, which resides within the Accelerate framework.

Comment: Yes. Actually there is FFT above those code. That's why I wonder what should I put in parameters.